# The result of the expression is always true

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, linq

I made a left join in linq and the value of UserId is NULLABLE (not in the table) but in the join and visual studio shows this warning.

I think this is a false positive because the code works well when userid is null IsSelected is false.

UserPrivilege class

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class UserPrivileges
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int PrivilegeId { get; set; }

    public virtual Privileges Privileges { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}
```

The linq query:

```
using (var dataContext = new MyEntities())
{
List<UserPrivilegesModel> result = (from privileges in dataContext.Privileges
                                    join userPrivileges in dataContext.UserPrivileges on privileges.Id equals userPrivileges.PrivilegeId into tmpUserPrivileges
                                    from userPrivileges in tmpUserPrivileges.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                        //where userPrivileges.UserId == userId
                                    select new UserPrivilegesModel { IsSelected = (userPrivileges.UserId != null), Description = privileges.Description, PrivilegeId = privileges.Id }).ToList();
return result;
}
```

[image]

On Linq userid == null is TRUE 
[image]

SQL SCRIPT:

```
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Privileges]    Script Date: 07/12/2016 10:35:21 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Privileges](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Privileges] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[UserPrivileges]    Script Date: 07/12/2016 10:35:21 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserPrivileges](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PrivilegeId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UserPrivileges_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC,
    [PrivilegeId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[UserProfile]    Script Date: 07/12/2016 10:35:21 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserProfile](
    [UserId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](56) NOT NULL,
    [Enabled] [smallint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__UserProf__1788CC4CB96C92F3] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [UQ__UserProf__C9F28456208EB813] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [UserName] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserPrivileges]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_UserPrivileges_Privileges] FOREIGN KEY([PrivilegeId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Privileges] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserPrivileges] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_UserPrivileges_Privileges]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserPrivileges]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_UserPrivileges_UserProfile] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[UserProfile] ([UserId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserPrivileges] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_UserPrivileges_UserProfile]
GO
```

SQL RELATIONSHIP

[image]

Comment: You should make your property nullable.

Comment: In the future, please make sure to include relevant code in the question *as text*. Images are not mobile-friendly, nor does it allow users to copy+paste your code into an answer. Anyone who wants to supply you with a code-based answer has to re-type your code.

Comment: I can't the class is auto-generated.

Comment: I included the code.

Comment: Should you be checking `userPrivlages == null` not `userPrivlages.UserId == null`? Also, should the 2nd from and the join be using the same name?

Comment: Thanks @Scott Chamberlain, this is the correct answer!

Comment: I turned my comment in to an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should you be checking userPrivlages == null not userPrivlages.UserId == null? Also, should the 2nd from and the join be using the same name?

Try correcting those issues.

Comment: I will change the names but it works with same name too! All the object (line) is null and now the warning is disappeared. thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The type in the *database* may be nullable, but the type in the *code* is not.  `UserId` is of type `int`, which can never be `null`.  (Hence the error.)  So presumably on a class somewhere you have something like this:

```
public int UserId { get; set; }
```

To make the type nullable, you would want this:

```
public int? UserId { get; set; }
```

Or, if you prefer, this:

```
public Nullable<int> UserId { get; set; }
```

This could have implications in other code not shown here about how to use that property, since you're changing the property's type.  But this will allow that property to carry a null value.

Comment: UserId is in <auto-generated> class from database! :(

Comment: @Evilripper: Then either the value can not be null or you're using a broken code-generating tool.

Answer (score 0):

userPrivaleges.UserId is not nullable, therefore (userPrivalegs.UserId != null) will always be true.

Comment: I try with userid == null and the it return TRUE!

Comment: I think the problem is with how your trying to perform the query. I cant see your data model, but is there a relationship between a user and a collection of user privaleges?

Comment: please see the accepted answer, I committed a mistake because I check the field and not all the object (In sql standard the left join returns null fields in linq returns objects). If I check the object is null the warning disappears.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, i'm just now curious.

Comment: I added script sql and rel schema have fun! :D

Comment: I know its totally unrealted now, but as  a heads up, there is no point in having an Id column on the UserPrivileges table. Your Primary key of the UserId and PrivilageId ensures that no duplicate entries can be stored in the table. You should be able to navigate from a UserProfile object directly to the assoicated privelages. Are you using Linq to Sql here?

Comment: You're right, but I always put an id for all tables (I know that's wrong but it can return very useful).
I'm using entity framework database first and mvc 5. I must develop an UI with checkboxes privileges -> isSelected is for the checkbox, if there isn't the row user hasn't the privilege. I think in this way is more efficient but yeah I should navigate from profile object (but I need all privileges to show all privileges checkable).